# How to enable XDebug extension on my php?

Tags: php

I am running php on a macbook pro running mountain lion.
Mountain lion comes with XDebug pre-installed, so based on a tutorial I've found , I made three steps.
First I've uncomment this line in my php.ini :

```
zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
```

Secondly I've uncomment this line in my php.ini :

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

And finally I restarted the apache server with :

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

The problem is that I see no xdebug appearing in my php details when I run a phpinfo().
Thank you.

PS : The path of the above xdebug.so file is correct.

Comment: does /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so file exist?

Comment: Yes, I've already mention that in the PS.

Comment: Check the server log files. They tell you what the problem is.

Comment: Which log file do you mean my friend?

Comment: Did you edit the correct php.ini? Look in your `phpinfo()` output for the path to the `php.ini` it is actually using. There are often multiples.

Comment: Yes this is the correct php.ini that phpinfo function reports.

Comment: For me, the xdebug.so file doesn't exist in the correct directory. Where can I find and download it?

Comment: please take a look on this blog it will be a great start 
https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am answering my own question because Mountain Lion is a special case when it comes to running XDebug.

[As you can see here,](https://github.com/liip/php-osx/issues/41)
mountain lion comes with an older `xdebug.so` library. So the user must re-compile the library himself.

Here is how to do it.

1. [Download the latest version here.](http://www.xdebug.org/download.php) (We get the file under the
   `source` link.)
2. Unpack the downloaded file with `tar -xvzf xdebug-2.2.1.tgz`
3. Run `cd xdebug-2.2.1`
4. Run `phpize`
5. Run `./configure`
6. Run `make`
7. Run `sudo cp modules/xdebug.so
   /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626`
8. Restart the web server with `sudo apachectl restart`

Comment: Worked like a champ!. The only thing I had to add was:
    // `/etc/php.ini`
    `zend_extension=xdebug.so`
    `[xdebug]`
    `xdebug.remote_enable=On`
    `xdebug.remote_host=localhost`
    `xdebug.remote_port=9000`

Answer (score 4):

Check you are editing the same php.ini that shows up in phpinfo() in the broswer.

Here are my settings (I'm also on a Macbook Pro on Mountain Lion btw):

```
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 999
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 99999
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 100


;zend_extension_ts=php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Works for me. Does any of that help?

Comment: My php.in file (and it is the one that the browser uses, the one that phpinfo() reports) contains only three lines with the xdebug string :
    --> zend_extension="/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"

--> ;xdebug.idekey="macgdbp"

--> xdebug.remote_enable=1

Comment: I've done these changes but still no luck.Searching for xdebug in the phpinfo() returned php page, returns nothing.Can you upload somewhere your phpinfo() result?

Comment: This is my phpinfo page in a viewable form :

Answer (score 0):

[This set of instructions worked for me.](http://dokimay.com/index.php/mac-osx/56-configuring-xdebug-on-osx-mountain-lion)

It successfully uses `OSX Mountain Lion's` native `Apache2` and `XDebug` together with `MacGDBp` and a Safari extension called `XDebug Helper`.

Comment: You should put the instructions (or at least a summary of them) just in case the link is broken.

Comment: And now the link broke, this is the exact reason why you shouldn't post links as answers.