# XDebug configuration missing from php.ini in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I've just installed the latest XAMPP for PHP 5.6 from the official website,  and I need to enable Xdebug, I find that the file `php_xdebug.dll` exists in the `C:\xampp\php\ext` , but there is no `[XDebug]` config at all in the `php.ini` and I have no idea how to make it work. It should be installed by default and pre-configured, we need just to uncomment the xdebug config in `php.ini` but it's not the case. I even tried to install it again using `PECL` commmand `pecl install xdebug` but I get the following error :

```
pecl install xdebug
downloading xdebug-2.5.0.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-2.5.0.tgz (267,640 bytes)
.........done: 267,640 bytes
ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\docs\xdebug\contrib
```

And in PHPStorm when I choose to add the interpreter by selecting the `php.exe` in the XAMPP directory, it says `Debugger : Not installed` too.

I re-installed XAMPP, but I still have the same problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try downloading other XAMPP version to get the variables of php.ini or check xdebug documentation and just declare them: https://xdebug.org/docs/basic

Comment: @FabianoAraujo I did, but there is no xdebug config in other xampp versions too.

Comment: Double installing things _never_ solved any problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41290093/trouble-configuring-xdebug-for-phpstorm-on-xampp-for-mac/41348770#41348770

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13535077/1906372

Comment: Most php distributions use a module configuration folder these days. Since `xampp` is nothing but a distribution of well known packages IÄd expect they also follow that path. So look for some `xdebug.xxxxx` file in a configuration folder whos files are included into the `php.ini` file.

Comment: Take a look on this tutorial and my answer https://hubpages.com/technology/Local-PHP-Debugging-with-XDebug-Atom-and-XAMPP

Answer (score 8):

For more details, you can find a tutorial that explains step by step procedure
[php-debugging-with-xdebug-atom-and-xampp](https://medium.com/@arunjos007/php-debugging-with-xdebug-atom-and-xampp-ba0ac795951d)

As per this tutorial please follow these steps its works like a charm:

**Steps to Install Xdebug:**

1. Download [xdebug-2.4.0.tgz](http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.4.0.tgz)
2. Unpack the downloaded file

   ```
   # navigate to the downloaded file
   $ cd ~/Downloads

   $ tar -xvzf xdebug-2.4.0.tgz
   $ cd xdebug-2.4.0
   ```
3. run phpize

   ```
   $ phpize

   # example output
   Configuring for:
   PHP Api Version:         20131106
   Zend Module Api No:      20131226
   Zend Extension Api No:   220131226

   #Error possibilty
   Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
   $PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

   #In the above error case you need to install autoconf using below command(MAC) and rerun phpize
   $ brew install autoconf
   ```

   The phpsize command is used to prepare the build environment for a
   PHP extension.
4. Configure it by run:

   ```
   $ ./configure
   ```
5. run make

   ```
   $ make
   ```

A successful install will have created xdebug.so file.

**Steps to Configure Xdebug:**

A successful install will have created xdebug.so and put it into the PHP extensions directory.

1. You must copy this file to XAMPP php extension directory for that
   run:-

   ```
   $ sudo cp modules/xdebug.so /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303
   ```
2. Finally update `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini` and add
   the following lines to it

   ```
   [Xdebug]
   zend_extension = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so
   xdebug.remote_enable=1
   xdebug.remote_connect_back=On
   xdebug.remote_port="9000"
   xdebug.profiler_enable=0
   xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
   xdebug.remote_mode=req
   xdebug.remote_autostart=true
   ```
3. Restart Apache using XAMPP’s manager-osx

Congratz! You have completed!! To verify you successfully installed & configured XDebug, open the XAMPP phpinfo.php file in a web browser, for example, http://localhost/dashboard/phpinfo.php.

- Search for XDebug section in PHPInfo details. If it exists, you successfully have done your installation
  OR
- In another browser window or tab, open https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and copy the phpinfo.php page content in the first window or tab and paste it into the textbox on the xdebug.org page. Then submit for analysis, it will give a summary of your installation status.

Comment: The wizard doesn't open for me. I get the summary and then nothing else.

Comment: 1st link is dead

Answer (score 4):

Safest was is to use [XDebug wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard.php) that will give you step by step instructions on how to install on your own machine. Then [update your php.ini](https://gist.github.com/tomasfejfar/4e8e27ece29b142a7ec7f54f4fa44872) (tune to your needs)

*Note:* Wizard will give you instructions for what SAPI it receives `phpinfo()` contents from. So if you fill CLI `phpinfo()` output you will get instructions for your PHP CLI. If you paste `phpinfo()` from a server page you will get instructions for that.

Comment: If I could give you 2 ups I would. Forgot about this - lifesaver!

Comment: Happy it helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

First copy your phpinfor() content form. paste the [xdebug wizard][1] [1]: https://xdebug.org/wizard. then download the xdebug.dll. after that  follow this steps

- Remove the exists php_xdebug.dill and paste the xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
- update the php.ini like this

  [Xdebug]  zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
  xdebug.remote_enable=1  debug.remote_autostart=true

Comment: Thank you! I've missed the php.ini configs!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for xdebug not working even after xdebug has been installed in NetBeans +xampp [here](https://articlebin.michaelmilette.com/making-xdebug-work-with-netbeans-on-windows/). The idea is you have to use all the settings for php.ini mentioned here and not just the usual ones mentioned in forums.